# Implicit declaration of strlcpy and strlcat even with "string.h" included

Tags: man

Gcc throws an error when I try to call the functions `strlcpy` or `strlcat` in a C file:

```
error : implicit declaration of strlcpy
error : implicit declaration of strlcat
```

In what library can I find those functions, and their man page? I included `string.h` but it doesn't change anything. I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 and gcc 4.8.4

Comment: `man strlcpy` will display their man page. If you're having problems with your code, you need to **post the code**, **post the compiler command line**, and do it on [so] since programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: `strlcpy()` and similar are available in libc on most UNIX variants. Linux is an exception as a former glibc maintainer did not like them even though he was not able to explain why or to point to a better concept. Software that ports to Linux usually implements own versions of these functions.

Comment: @schily note that this is no longer true: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=454a20c8756c9c1d55419153255fc7692b3d2199

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Ubuntu, Mint, and relatives, `strlcpy` and `strlcat` are available in the [`libbsd-dev` package](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libbsd-dev). Run

```
sudo apt-get install libbsd-dev
```

This will install the libraries, header files, and man pages.

To use the functions from C code, add the line

```
#include <bsd/string.h>
```

to your files, and add `-lbsd` , or the more portable `$(pkg-config --libs libbsd)` , to your `gcc` command line to link the library.

Comment: Note that the functions are now available in glibc 2.38 and above: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=454a20c8756c9c1d55419153255fc7692b3d2199 (which is available e.g. in Ubuntu 23.10)